# Can a class and a function have a common name in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

It looks like there is a function as well as a class associated with the name `cv2.VideoCapture`.

Is it possible for a class and a function that share a common name?

My guess is that at this moment cv2.VideoCapture represents a class and a function as well.

```
>>>import cv2

>>>print(cv2.VideoCapture)
<built-in function VideoCapture>  

>>>camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
>>>print(type(camera))
<class 'cv2.VideoCapture'>
```

Comment: Couldn't a function return a class?

Comment: indeed it could. however, it prints a class which has same name just as the function. i am expecting a class that has different name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All depends on what you call "name"...

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> _Foo = Foo
>>> def Foo():
...     return _Foo()
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(Foo)
<function Foo at 0x7f74a5fec8c0>
>>> print(type(f))
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>>
```

As you can see, you here have a function exposed as `Foo` *and* having it's `__name__` == "Foo", and a class exposed as `_Foo` but having `__name__` ==  "Foo" too.

To answer your question: you cannot have the same name (=> variable) bound to more than one object  at a given time in a given namespace. But you can have has many objects has you want having the same value for a  `.__name__` attribute.

Comment: anyway i am satisfied with your answer and it is clear. but i don't see the advantage of using one name for a class and a function in one python module(cv2 in this case)..

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked the `OpenCV` source code in order to check out what or why is going on in this specific case, but in theory this can be possible if your function returns an instance of a class with the same name.

consider the file cv2.py with the following content

```
def VideoCapture(_):
    class VideoCapture(object):
        pass
    return VideoCapture()
```

usage:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.VideoCapture
<function VideoCapture at 0x7f70d36069b0>
>>> 
>>> camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>>> type(camera)
<class 'cv2.VideoCapture'>
```